# BoxConstraints forces an infinite height

Tags: flutter

```
child:Column(
children: <Widget>[
  Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    width: 100.0,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Text('hello'),
  ),)
```

in this,when i make height:double.infinity,it gives error in run saying **BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.**but when i give height manually it work fine.
can anyone explain me why this happening.

Comment: Are you asking that if you were to write `height: 250.0` then why the height is not infinite?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please tell us what you are trying to achieve? Maybe the widgets you are using are not the best ones for your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

How about this one.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
//                height: double.infinity,
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('hello'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Full screen hight sample.]

Answer (score 4):

`BoxConstraints forces an infinite height`

## Why This Happens

You're asking to render an infinite height object without a height constraint... Flutter can't do that.

---

`Column` lays out children in two phases:

- Phase 1: `non-Flex` items (anything **not** `Expanded`, `Flexible` or `Spacer`)

  - done in *unconstrained space*
- Phase 2: `Flex` items (`Expanded`,`Flexible`, `Spacer` only)

  - done with *remaining space*

#### Phase 1

- `Column's` phase 1 vertical layout is done in *unbounded* space. That means:

  - no vertical constraint → no height limit
  - any widget with infinite height will throw the above error
  - you can't render an infinite height object in an infinite height constraint... that's goes on forever

#### Phase 2

- after Phase 1 widgets have taken **as much space as they intrinsically need**, phase 2 `Flex` items **share the remaining/leftover space**

  - the remaining space is calculated from incoming constraints minus Phase 1 widgets dimensions
  - `double.infinity` height will expand to use up the remaining space

#### Infinite Height is OK

Here's an example of using infinite height on a `Container` inside a `Column`, which is fine:

```
class ColumnInfiniteChildPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                height: double.infinity, // ← perfectly fine
                  child: Text('Column > Container > Text')),
            ),
            Text('Column > Text')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Remove the `Flexible` and the error will be thrown.

Answer (score 3):

This means that you can't offer inifite height to the container. It's obvious behaviour if you don't provide the contraints to height.

You have to specify limited height to the container so that flutter can render it, if you offer it infinite it how can flutter render that and up to which constraints it would do that !

Rather you can set **double.infinity** to width and flutter will successfully render that because by default flutter has constraints for width it will set width to width of screen.

Considering that you have to provide height as that of screen you can use MediaQuery for that

```dart
Widget yourMethod(or build)(BuildContext context){
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Column(
        children:<Widget>[
            Container(
                height:screenHeight,//but this will be height of whole screen. You need to substract screen default paddings and height of appbar if you have one
                width:100.0,
                ....
            )
        ]);

    }
```

Hope this helps ! 
Happy coding..

Comment: Also check out yuu woods answer, thats more accurate.

Comment: This will lead to Bottom Overflowed by some pixels error.